# How come "ls -U" on a directory that contains many files takes some time, while doing "ls -U | head" returns an answer immediately?

Tags: ls

When you want to get a sample of file names from a directory that contains many files, it is advised to do "ls -U | head", because otherwise doing "ls" alone can take quite some time.

However, why doesn't "ls -U" by it self does not start returning outputs as soon as it ran?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU ls -U  means unsorted output, so it does not need to wait for all the directory contents to start printing them.

head will close stdin and quit after a small number of lines. When the writer to the pipe, ls in this case, has no more readers, it will quit. This will flush all the I/O involved after only a small number of lines, making it seem snappy in interactive use.

Further reading: [Process not closing when stdin is closed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/265464/86954)

---

A noticeable to humans delay in listing directory contents is a sign of exceeding practical limits. Lots of files in a directory means large file system metadata, and so a lot of I/O.  Lots typically means hundreds of thousands of files, even for production tested file systems.

Beyond a certain number of files, it makes sense to reconsider alterative directory layouts and databases. Short term, put the problem volume on fast SSDs to make its performance tolerable.